# Display a token's expiration date to a user

Tags: hash, account-security, attack-prevention

We use multiple kinds of token in our system for :

- Invitation to joint a group
- Account creation (validate if the user possesses the email address)
- Validate email address

The tokens are sent in a link in an email. I have been asked to include the expiration date of the tokens. However, it feels as if it could help hackers to plan an enumeration attack.

Is it a flaw in our security to show the expiration date of the token?

Comment: *"However, it feels as if it could help hackers to plan an enumeration attack."* - why do you feel this way? As long as the token is long enough and not created in a predictable way (i.e. long random string would be sufficient) a enumeration attack is infeasible no matter if the expiration date is shown or not. Unfortunately it is unknown if the token you use works as I described.

Comment: The token is indeed a long random string. I feel this way because an attacker would know e.g., that the token expires in 40 days and with the length of the token, he could estimate the chance of finding a valid token.

Comment: *", he could estimate the chance of finding a valid token"*  - with a proper random token this chance would be essentially zero, i.e. guessing the token would be practically impossible no matter how long the token is valid.